# Menu with ajax load not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I create a menu with ajax load. I have 4 zones and each zone have states. What i want is on hover on zone, i need to display all states in that zone. I write following code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="zoneLevel">
    <li id="1" onmouseover="get_states_list(this.id);">East Zone
        <span id="stateContainer" style="display:none;">States</span>
    </li>
    <li id="2">West Zone</li>
    <li id="3">North Zone</li>
    <li id="4">South Zone</li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
function get_states_list(zone_id) {
    //alert(zone_id);
    var last_slug_a1 = $(".homeLeftContainer .single:last").attr("id");  

    $('span#stateContainer').html('<img src="img/loader.gif">');

    $.post("modules/frontend/ajax/load_state.php?action=get&zone_id="+zone_id,

    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
            $("span#stateContainer").html(data);        
        } 
    });
    $(".stateContainer").css("display", "block");
    $(".stateHederMenu").css("display", "block");
}
</script>
```

everything's good.

Problem started when i mouse hover to state (which i get with ajax file), it again call **get_states_list(this.id)** function.  Can you please point the error.

Comment: Remove inline event handling, and do it in jquery

Comment: You can not go to state with mouse, without hovering the `li` element with your event handler, try rememeber in your handler that You have execute event handler, you can do it with jquery `one` method

Comment: can you please give any example for reference. :)

Comment: @Łukasz Szewczak is right. maybe the below answer will help you

Comment: @GautamMenariya I put example below as answer

Answer (score 1):

It's because again you are hovering the li, the actual span is inside the li and hence the function is triggered again. So just use another tag maybe `<a>,<p>,<span>` or anything after li and close the word. so it wont trigger again unless you mouse over to the word.

```
<ul class="zoneLevel">
<li id="1" >
      <a onmouseover="get_states_list(this.id);">East Zone</a>
         <span id="stateContainer" style="display:none;">
            States
         </span>
 </li>
<li id="2">West Zone</li>
<li id="3">North Zone</li>
<li id="4">South Zone</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with jQuery

```
$('.zoneLevel li').one('mouseover',function (){
 get_states_list($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

And fiddle for this situation [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukaszewczak/s8D2g/)